# Update or insert records to the same table based on a similar table but with conditions

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, plsql, etl, merge, plsql-developer

I'm tryin to update or insert records on the same table based on a similar table using Merge but based on the count of records in the source table.

I have 2 tables say one is **POV** [pov, dc, item](the table where I want to insert/ update), the other table is **KLN** [pov, wh , item].

The source table for the merge is by joining these 2 tables, **POV** and **KLN based on [pov, wh, item]** so the excess records for the same [pov, item] that are present in the second table KLN should be inserted/ updated based on the count of records that are generated in the join with same [pov, item].

- If only one record is generated for the same [pov, item] combination
  I want to update my target table.
- If multiple records are generated I want to insert these records into
  the table.

**I'm unable to use `GROUP BY`** since I need the value of [wh] as well [pov, wh, item] all the records have distinct [wh] for the same [pov, wh] based on the count of records for the same I want to update my table.

Here's what I wanna do:

```
merge into POV {target} using
 (select distinct POV.pov, POV.item, **KLN.WH**
       ,count(/*of the number of [WH] generated with same pov and item*/)
  from POV, KLN 
   where POV.pov = KLN.pov
   and POV.item = kln.item ) as { source }
on (
    target.pov = source.pov
    and target.item = source.item
    and source.count = 1
    )
 when matched 
    then update
       set tgt.pov = **source.WH**
 when not matched
     then insert
```

I can take care of this. I just need a solution to help me get the count as well as distinct WH from KLN table.

This is my first time asking a question, please don't mind. I'll be really thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well then a [windowed](https://www.databasestar.com/sql-partition-by/) function could help you.
You could try the following code:

```
MERGE INTO POV target
USING (
  SELECT DISTINCT POV.pov, POV.item, KLN.wh,
    COUNT(KLN.wh) OVER (PARTITION BY POV.pov, POV.item) AS cnt
  FROM POV, KLN
  WHERE POV.pov = KLN.pov
    AND POV.item = KLN.item
) source ON (
  target.pov = source.pov
  AND target.item = source.item
  AND source.cnt = 1
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET target.dc = source.wh
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (pov, dc, item)
  VALUES (source.pov, source.wh, source.item);
```

The `PARTITION BY` clause sets the range of records that will be used for each "GROUP" within the OVER clause.

In your example, `cnt` will return the number of `KLN.wh` within that `POV.pov, POV.item` for every record (you still return every record in the emp table). So you can use the count in the `merge` and also you have `KLN.wh` record in the update part.

Here is a demo for your case: https://dbfiddle.uk/codWTkoI

> **NOTE!**
> You wrote "set tgt.pov = **source.WH**" but you can't use the same column in the `ON` an the `UPDATE` part so I overwrite it.